# How to change the values of a dictionary to the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which looks like

```
D = {k1: [v1, v2, v3]; k2: [v1, v2]; k3: [v3, v4, v2] }
```

How could I generate a dictionary from `D` that looks like

```
D* = {v1: [k1, k2]; v2: [k1, k2, k3]; v3:[k1, k3], v4:[k3]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for k, v in D.items():
    for i in v:
        result.setdefault(i, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
for k, v in D.items():
    for j in v:
        d[j] = d.get(j, []) + [k]
print(d)
```